# C# Universal app not loading

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I'm trying to write an app that gets the price of cryptocurrencies constantly. The CallAPI() function gets the price from an online API in JSON format, parses it, then sends it to a text block on the frontend of the app. It is running in a while loop with a short break between:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        KrakenConnector KC = new KrakenConnector();

        while (true)
        {
            CallAPI(KC, 0);
            CallAPI(KC, 1);
            CallAPI(KC, 2);
            CallAPI(KC, 3);
            CallAPI(KC, 4);
            CallAPI(KC, 5);
            Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
        }
    }
```

I'm just getting the default splash screen of Windows Universal apps, and it's not going into the actual app. How can I fix this? Why isn't it going into the app? Should I not be setting the text block in the CallAPI function?

Comment: Well since the `MainPage` method never exits, perhaps that's the reason it doesn't get any further? You should probably look to re-engineer this method so that it is called with a timer perhaps.

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I am trying to look through the .net framework at the args that the timer class, but I don't know where to find the explorer thing...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private bool isLoaded = true;

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.WorkItAsync();
    this.Unloaded += (s, e) => this.isLoaded = false;
}

private async Task WorkItAsync()
{
    var KC = new KrakenConnector();

    while (this.isLoaded)
    {
        CallAPI(KC, 0);
        CallAPI(KC, 1);
        CallAPI(KC, 2);
        CallAPI(KC, 3);
        CallAPI(KC, 4);
        CallAPI(KC, 5);
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `MainPage` constructor never exits. Furthermore, you're doing the calls *and* the `Task.Delay` on the UI thread, which is a no-no. You should do it on a background thread.

Here's a skeleton of a better approach:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage
{
    private bool running;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        running = true;

        // Start background thread
        Task.Run(
            async () =>
            {
                int counter = 0;
                while (running)
                {
                    // UI updates must happen on the UI thread;
                    // we use the Dispatcher for this:
                    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(
                        CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                        () => test.Text = counter.ToString());
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                    ++counter;
                }
            });
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        running = false;
    }
```

The corresponding XAML:

```
<Page
    x:Class="App2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock
            x:Name="test"
            FontSize="24"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Margin="0,24,0,0" />
        <!-- The button doesn't do anything; it's just to show that the UI is live -->
        <Button
            Content="Hello, world!"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Margin="0,24,0,0" />
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Using a `bool` to control the loop is a bit simpleminded, though; a better approach is to use a `CancellationTokenSource`, which also has the ability to stop `Task.Delay` dead in its tracks. Here's another take:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage
{
    private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        CancellationToken token = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

        // Start background thread
        Task.Run(
            async () =>
            {
                int counter = 0;
                while (true)
                {
                    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        // Stop the loop; we're moving away from the page
                        break;
                    }

                    // UI updates must happen on the UI thread;
                    // we use the Dispatcher for this:
                    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(
                        CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
                        () => test.Text = counter.ToString());
                    await Task.Delay(1000, token);
                    ++counter;
                }
            });
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        cancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
    }
}
```